# Function accepting only 2 over 6 parameters. Func_num_args returns 2

Tags: php, function, arguments

I'm having a weird issue. Basically I have a function, which is called by the smarty template engine, and should accept 6 parameters. Actually the problem is, that it is only accepting 2!

And even more weird, calling `func_num_args()` inside that function gived me too... but have a look a it

```
function smarty_modifier_truncate($string, $length = 80, $etc = '...', $break_words = false, $middle = false, $charset = 'UTF-8')
{
var_dump($break_words);
var_dump(func_num_args());

if (!$length)
    return '';

if (Tools::strlen($string) > $length)
{
    $length -= min($length, Tools::strlen($etc));
    if (!$break_words && !$middle)
        $string = preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/u', '', Tools::substr($string, 0, $length+1, $charset));
    return !$middle ? Tools::substr($string, 0, $length, $charset).$etc : Tools::substr($string, 0, $length/2, $charset).$etc.Tools::substr($string, -$length/2, $length, $charset);
}
else
    return $string;
}
```

Those other parameters are set, since "break words" is being outputted, and if i change them ,the effects is noticeble. Really weird. is there any solution?

PHP version 5.4.3 running on local wamp

Answer (score 2):

`func_num_args()` returns the number of arguments, that are *actually* passed to the function when calling, not the number of accepted arguments. That wouldn't eve be possible, because PHP always accepts an arbitrary number of arguments

```
function foo () {
  var_dump(func_num_args());
  var_dump(func_get_args());
}
foo(1, 'a', null, true);
```

http://codepad.org/nhqgb5kK

Comment: Yeah, but actually the function is being passed 5 arguments, that's the problem